# Google Analytics Java API: Cannot access more than 7 dimensions

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to access 12 dimensions from GA API.
When i did the same with 6-7 parameters, it worked fine.
I searched for the limits & quota but couldn't find anything 
regarding this.

---

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested 12 dimensions; only 7 are allowed.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requested 12 dimensions; only 7 are allowed."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.tomvogten.analytics.View.readData(View.java:165)
    at com.tomvogten.analytics.Downloader.main(Downloader.java:85)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tomvogten.analytics.View.writeData(View.java:191)
    at com.tomvogten.analytics.Downloader.main(Downloader.java:86)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a limitation explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#dimensions):

*"You can supply a maximum of 7 dimensions in any query."*

and that is why your request got rejected.